# Removing index.htm from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress blog which is functioning just fine - the URLs are set to Month/Day/Year and everything on the front-end looks and functions fine.

However, when checking my stats and Google Webmaster Tools, there's tons of 404s that look like this:

```
http://theURL.com/normal-wordpress-url/index.htm
```

Of course, `index.htm` does not exist at the end of the WordPress URL, so the search engine is given a 404.

I have no idea what's causing this, as everything works fine for humans.

So basically, I need a way to tell search engines to forget about the index.htm at the end of the URL.

I've tried this in the `.htacess` with no luck:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.htm?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.htm?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: With those rules, when you go to `http://theURL.com/normal-wordpress-url/index.htm`, you don't get redirected?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm just taken to a "Nothing found" WordPress page.

Comment: And you have these rules before any wordpress related stuff?

Comment: That was it - I had it after the WordPress stuff. The only change I had to make was to add the /blog/ directory to the rewrite rule. 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.htm?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.htm?$ "/blog/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are different problems in here that may need solution:

**Problem 1:** If the crawler is the one pointing to this page there are two things that you might need to do:

- Try to go to Webmaster and delete "index.htm"
- Try to create a robot that will disallow "index.htm" from being seen on Google Crawler.

**Problem 2:** If you have distributed your urls to point to this url, Google Webmaster can tell you which webpage it is coming from exactly.

- So, try to make sure that all the links pointing to "index.htm" are removed from all other urls.

Comment: Interesting - the site has a custom HTML homepage, with a WordPress installation in the "/blog/" directory. At first, the thought of deleting index.htm wasn't possible, but I just noticed that it's redirecting to index.php anyways. Maybe I'll try removing index.htm altogether to see if it fixes the issue. Webmaster tools isn't telling us which pages are pointing to index.htm unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I had wrong comments on the previous... If you are going to go to 'Traffic>Links To Your Site>Who Links The Most>More>Download More Sample Links', you are going to find the links. You will get all the links, but I guess you need to clean up a bit. Deleting "index.htm" on your wordpress directory will also fix your issue since all wordpress files are .php.